# Migrate data from MySQL to PostgreSQL In Azure

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, azure, migration

I want to perform a full db migration from MySQL to PostgreSQL with (near to) zero downtime, in order to do that, I want to use a tool that would perform not only full db migration but also allow continuous replication of the data chagnes to postgres in real time. In AWS there is DMS service that allows you to migrate data between different kind databases, but unfortunately Azure DMS only support migration to the same db, so e.g. MySQL -> MySQL, Postgres -> Postgres. Is there any way to set up continuous data replication from mysql to postgresql in Azure?